# Ability to listen for events(non chart events) on a react-google-chart

Tags: reactjs, google-visualization

We are currently building a reactjs application. One of the component requires the use of [react-google-chart](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-charts)  to display an annotation chart.

Am able to get the chart displayed without issues - a requirement specifies that on the annotations table to the right we have a button for each row and clicking on that should trigger a event that could access a method on the parent component (i.e a parent component holding the Chart)

Here is a sandbox code for this 
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-google-charts-annotation-chart-d4px2

Note the 'Click me' buttons on the annotation table next to the chart

Solutions Tried

- Initially tried with 'select' event of the google annotation
  chart(passing in chartEvents) but those events are fired on the chart
  but would not be fired when clicked on the annotation table
- Tried passing in a function as a property to the react-google-chart componet as shown but from button onClick there was no way i could refer this function via property like this.props.getDetail etc..

Ideally would like to see a solution where clicking the buttons on the annotation chart ....we are able to call a function on the parent component.
Currently cant access a function(#getDetail) in the parent component i.e App in the above example

Comment: i realize the select event won't work, but are you able to call methods on the parent from within the select event? if so, how? and we may be able to workout something using the ready event...

Comment: Even on 'select' was not able to call the parent function sorry if i mislead that am able to execute a parent function.

Comment: that's what I thought, I was able to add an event handler to the buttons during the ready event, but couldn't figure out how to connect to the parent...

Comment: a work around we put in place for this is showing the chart without annotations table and manually build a table next to it to achieve the above. To co-relate the points on chart with manually created table we use the bijective base 26 algorithm o generate the ID's